# php created select tag with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Good day this is my code of index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    function show_month(var) {
        if (windows.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php?q="+var,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<?php
    $from = (date('Y'));
    $to = 2050;
    echo '<form>';
    echo '<select name="year" onchange="show_month(this.value)">';

    for($y = $from; $y <= $to; $y++) {
        echo "<option value=$y>{$y}</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<form>';
?>

<div id="txtHint"><b>here will be info</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is code of my month.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <?php
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        echo $q;
        if ($q == 2015) {
            echo "actual year";
        }
        else {
            echo "unactual year";
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

As you see I created select tag with php so I can make multiple options of year just by using loop and I want that if I select year 2015 `javascript` should print message actual year but it isn't working I think that problem is somewhere in select or sending value *can someone more intelligent than me look into this code and tell me whats is wrong?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js code does not have the response code.  Also you have a few other errors in your code which will cause issues for you.

**show_month(var)** you cannot have var as this specific to JS, change it to something else.

**windows.XMLHttpRequest**  This is window not windows.

In order to show what you need use;
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
in your response if.

```
    <script>
    function show_month(t) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php?q="+t,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

and finally you don't need **`<!DOCTYPE html>`** in your month.php if you are just returning text (most likely you will never need a reason for it).

Comment: i dont wanna alert i just want that text "here will be info" will change to text line in month.php

Comment: ah ok, then just add; document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; instead of the alert.

Comment: i added but nothing changed

Comment: was my answer not useful enough?

Comment: yea it was too i didnt see those error and missspelling but dont worry you are great too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is missing code to handle server response

```
<script>
function show_month(var) {
    if (windows.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
   }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php?q="+var,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: i added handle to response but it didnt helped still my message isnt changing :(

Comment: you answer was most usefull i just used lowercase for innerHTML now its working like i wanted thx